# Timezone Asia/Kolkata changed to PST

Tags: 18.04, time, timezone

**What I did:**

Ran this command:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime
```

**What happened:**

My local time changed to PST. Now I ran:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata /etc/localtime
```

But my system time didn't change back to IST. Instead, it's showing PST's time with the IST label.

[image: screenshot showing the wrong time zone displayed]

(In picture: I'm pointing to IST Kolkata, but the time zone highlighted is Los Angeles. This may explain my problem.)

**Expected result:**

I want Asia/Kolkata to be back to normal.

**P.S.:** With the command

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Kolkata
```

the timezone changed to IST with PST's time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstalling and reinstalling `tzdata` solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get remove tzdata
sudo apt-get install tzdata
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not the correct way to change the timezone in command line.

**To reset your clock:**

`sudo apt install ntpdate`

`sudo ntpdate -s ntp.ubuntu.com`

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

Select the correct timezone from the menu.

**Next time if you want to set your timezone from command line:**

`timedatectl set-timezone [Region]/[City]`

Comment: i want to change time with script file cmd that's why I used that, and may i know why is that a wrong way@Ifly777

Comment: instead of using `cp` more appropriate will be to create symbolic link using `ln`.  Something like `ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Zone/SubZone /etc/localtime`

Answer (score 0):

This will set timezone to Asia/Kolkata. `timedatectl` manages the time settings of your system.

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Kolkata
```

To view available list of timezones enter,

```
timedatectl list-timezones
```

**Edit :** I understand that your system S/W time is messed up. In this case use your hardware clock to set your system time by using the command below.

```
sudo hwclock --hctosys
```

Comment: this answer is not helping

Comment: This command only changes the time zone. In the case of OP the systemclock is now changed.

Comment: @Ifly777 I saw that now, updated my answer... thanks for pointing it out.